# What is the purpose of installing libfwup1 libwayland-egl1-mesa package while installing curl?

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, curl

I was trying to install curl to my new ubuntu machine and found a package libfwup1 libwayland-egl1-mesa which is supposed to be installed along with curl. So, i wanted to know what this command does and will it effect the system if removed accidently.

Comment: Those packages are not needed for installing curl AFAIK. How did you conclude that they are? Which command are you talking about?

Comment: Before installing anything, it's a good idea to first run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Im trying to figure it out, as im new to ubuntu.

Comment: According to [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/curl), neither of the above mentioned packages is a dependecy of `curl`. Are you sure they were installed while `curl` was installed? In my installation, libwayland-egl1-mesa exists because of VLC player and libfwup1 isn't a dependency of anything.

Comment: Yes after installing Ubuntu to my system for the first time. I tried to install curl for the 1st time and i got a prompt about the above packages. So, i was wondering whether these are the dependent packages to be installed along with the curl package